# Is there a way to Link the row height of 2 datagrids to always be the same?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 Datagrids that contain the same or similar strings. In some cases the strings are different enough to where the row height becomes misaligned. Is there anyway to link the row height of both Datagrids so that they both always equal the largest height? Note: The Itemsource of the grids will always have the same number of rows.

Thanks

Comment: You may concat the values into the single list and diaplay it in the singla `DataGrid` is there any other reason for splitting the data?

Comment: Thanks for the response. the primary reason for them to be split is that each string that appears in the datagrid needs to be compared with the same one of the other datagrid.Concatenating them presents me with the same issue that the texts won't be lined up.

Comment: Use different columns? In short you can't synchronize row height easily. Thus before doing that be sure that anything else is not suitable for you. Can you add a screenshot to clarify the question?

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by using different columns. The app consists of 2 different DataGrids each with 1 column. If you are suggesting placing the text in the same datagrid, unfortunately my the app specs require them to be separate. I cannot provide a screenshot at this time.

Comment: It can be done, but if the row heights were set to always be equal to the largest height, then the user could never resize them smaller again. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @RufusL Yes this is the desired behavior. user is not intended to resize the rows

Comment: And do you want all the rows to be the same size as the tallest row, or do you want all the rows in one control to be the same size as the largest for that row index? In other words, some rows may be short, some rows may be tall, but each equivalent row between the two dataGridViews will be the same size as the tallest of the two.

Comment: I also think by far the simplest would be to merge the two sets of data into one with 2 properties. Bind a collection of these to one datagrid itemssource and display in 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way to link the heights of two `DataGridViewRow` objects such that each row is the height of the taller between it and the row at the same index in the other grid is to simply find the tallest between the two rows and then set the `Height` property of the row at that index in both grids:

```
private void SetRowHeightsEqualToTallest(DataGridView first, DataGridView second)
{
    // Just in case, get the row count for the dgv with the fewest rows
    var rowCount = first.RowCount < second.RowCount ? first.RowCount : second.RowCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height > dataGridView2.Rows[i].Height)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows[i].Height = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height;
        }
        else if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Height > dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Height;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want *all* the rows of both grids to equal the tallest row between either grid, then we can do that instead:

```
private void SetRowHeightsEqualToTallest(DataGridView first, DataGridView second)
{
    // Get all the rows
    var allRows = first.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Union(second.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>());

    // Find the tallest height
    var tallestHeight = allRows.Max(row => row.Height);

    // Set the height of all the rows to the tallest height
    foreach (var row in allRows)
    {
        row.Height = tallestHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Just to double check your code blocks are using the DataGridView object which i believe is a win forms control. My Application is using the WPF variant which is DataGrid of which the accessibility these properties differs.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry I guess this is for a different type of object